# Meteor React component not updating on log out

Tags: meteor, reactjs, meteor-accounts, meteor-react

I have a page where it will show a different component based on if the user if logged in or out.

In the render area I have:

```
 var layout;
 if (Meteor.userId()) {
    layout = <BoxSignedIn />;
 } else {
    layout = <BoxSignedOut />;
 }

 return (

            layout                               
        ) 
  }
```

Now this does work if I sign out and refresh the app but will not work if I just sign out and do not refresh.

Here is the code for the signed in component:

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

```
export default class BoxSignedIn extends React.Component{

constructor(){
 super();   
 }

render(){   
 return (   
                   <div>signed in </div>

        ) 
}
}
```

Comment: Please try to format your code when posting to StackOverflow. It helps us understanding your questions faster.

Answer (score 4):

That's because React only updates the component when its state or props change, but `Meteor.userId()` is neither of those. You'll need to use `createComponent` to turn `Meteor.userId()` into a React property.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.userId ? <BoxSignedIn /> : <BoxSignedOut />;
  }
}

export default createContainer(() => {
  return {
    userId: Meteor.userId()
  };
}, MyComponent);
```